# Video Loop when it comes to the end

Tags: android, eclipse, video-streaming, android-videoview, vitamio

How to make the video to loop seamlessly as of now when it comes to an end of the clip and starts the clip again

`public class TvPlay extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener,
    OnErrorListener, OnPreparedListener {

```
    private VideoView mVideoView;
    private String url;
    private ProgressBar load;
    private TextView empty;
    private AdView mAdView;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

//                  Vitamio.isInitialized(this);
                    Vitamio.isInitialized(getApplicationContext());

```
                this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                setContentView(R.layout.tvplay);
                mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
                mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                Log.d("url=", getIntent().getStringExtra("url"));
                url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
                init();

            }

    public void init() {
        load = (ProgressBar) this.findViewById(R.id.load);
        empty = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.empty);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
        mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(this);
        Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(url);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        loading();
    }

    private void loading() {
        load.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void loadComplete(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        load.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        // vv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        empty.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mVideoView.start();
        mVideoView.resume();
    }

    private void error(String msg) {
        load.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        empty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (msg != null)
            empty.setText(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("ONLINE TV", "Prepared");
        loadComplete(mp);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("ONLINE TV", "Error");
        error("Unable to play this channel.");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("ONLINE TV", "Complete");
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

this  will make your video keep playing

```
 mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: iam using a streaming url . so this is not working for me